# Import/export xml with symfony 3. Where to begin?

Tags: xml, symfony

So I started making an app (shop) and I need to be able (as admin), to import xml files and also export orders to xml.
I looked around but I didnt find anything that could help me, or I didnt look in the right place.
Can someone point me in the right direction?? 
Im new to symfony 3 and any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `Serializer Component`.

Here is the doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

And the Cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html

There is a `XmlEncoder` that could be useful for your needs.